# Дать класс каждому первому элементу строки

Tags: javascript, html

Скажите, никак не соображу, как дать класс первому элементу в каждой строке каталога?
Допустим на компьютере выводиться по 5 элементов в строке, на планшете по 3, а на мобильниках по 1. Это тоже нужно учитывать.

```
<div class="category__block cont">

    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
            Название</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот ссылочка
https://jsfiddle.net/807hf2b4/1/
Нужно каждому первому элементу строки с классом category-item добавить класс first.
В примере это каждой 6 элемент, но при адаптации он может стать каждым первым или каждым четвертым.

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но для начала может определиться с `breakpoints`? Ну и стили лучше с `fiddle` в вопрос добавить.

Comment: @РустамГимранов А по существу что-то будет сегодня?))

Comment: @РустамГимранов ни кто не ерничает, вас просят на вопрос ответить, а не к форматированию придираться. Вопрос вы давно поняли и стили здесь роли никакой не играют, важна верстка, стили могут быть абсолютно любыми.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**
Если Вам надо всего лишь как-то визуально выделить первые элементы в строке, то можно обойтись вообще без js и добавлять не класс first элементам, а конкретные стили:

```css
.category__block {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 19%);
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.cont {
    padding: 0 80px;
}
.category-item {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,1,.15);
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 20px 66px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .25s all;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.category-item:nth-child(5n+1) {
      border-color: red;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .category__block {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 30%);
    }
    .category-item:nth-child(5n+1) {
      border-color: #e1e1e1;
    }
    .category-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
      border-color: red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .category__block {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 90%);
    }
    .category-item:nth-child(n) {
      border-color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="category__block cont">

 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

**Вариант с добавлением класса first**

Для начала (как верно отметил в комментарии Рустам Гимранов), Вам необходимо определиться с брейкпоинтами (потому что сейчас никакого адаптива у Вас нет, и совершенно непонятно, при какой ширине экрана каким элементам добавлять класс first).

А затем Вы просто проверяете ширину экрана (как при загрузке, так и при ресайзе), и добавляете/удаляете класс first для тех элементов, которым это надо.

В своём примере я задал брейкпоинты 1000 и 600 пикселей, а классу first для наглядности покрасил бордер в красный цвет.

```js
const addClassFirst = function() {
  let width = window.innerWidth;

  let categoryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.category-item');

  if(width < 600) {
    categoryItems.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className += ' first';
    })
  }
  else if(width >= 600 && width < 1000) {
    categoryItems.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className = 'category-item';
    });
    for(let i = 0; i < categoryItems.length; i += 3) {
      categoryItems[i].className += ' first';
    }
  }
  else {
    categoryItems.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className = 'category-item';
    });
    for(let i = 0; i < categoryItems.length; i += 5) {
      categoryItems[i].className += ' first';
    }
  }
}

addClassFirst();

window.onresize = function() {
  addClassFirst();
}
```

```css
.category__block {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 19%);
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.cont {
    padding: 0 80px;
}
.category-item {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,1,.15);
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 20px 66px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .25s all;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.category-item.first {
  border-color: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .category__block {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 30%);
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .category__block {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 90%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="category__block cont">

 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
 <div class="category-item">
  <a href="soevyij-sous.html" class="category-item_title">
   Название</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне нужно не визуально выделить, а присвоить класс каждому первому элементу строки, с целью потом сделать некие манипуляции. В частности, сделать открытие карточки товара как здесь: https://yakitoriya.ru/menu-dostavki/sushi

Comment: @Batyabest, ну так смотрите тогда "Вариант с добавлением класса first". Я ж специально 2 варианта дал

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, это можно сделать с помощью js, но я в нём не силён.

Чистым css, я бы реализовал это так (но это костыль, чисто как вариант для реализации):

1. создал бы 3 разных класса с одинаковыми стилями
2. Дальше, с помощью media query я бы сделал:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
   .first {
      style
   }

   .second {
      non-style
   }

   .third {
      non-style
   }
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
   .first {
      style
   }

   .second {
      non-style
   }

   .third {
      non-style
   }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
   .first {
      non-style
   }

   .second {
      style
   }

   .third {
      non-style
   }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
   .first {
      non-style
   }

   .second {
      none-style
   }

   .third {
      style
   }
}
```

при этом, конечно, поведение блоков на разных media должно быть предсказуемым (как вы и указали, 5 для десктопа, 3 для планшета, 1 для мобильников).